# how to add default element in sequence if is empty? using DefaultIfEmpty()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have query that maybe haven't any element on sequence and i want to add one element to sequence if is empty.

```
var results = _context.Documents.Select(document => document.MimeType).Distinct().ToList().DefaultIfEmpty("There is nothing to be used as MimeType");
```

but still sequence is empty however is used DefaultIfEmpty method.

Comment: How are you determining the sequence is truly empty? Is it possible there is surrounding code creating unintended side effects?

Comment: Using LinqPad:
var l = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(){ new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value")};
l.Select(kv => kv.Key).Distinct().ToList().DefaultIfEmpty("(empty)").Dump();

l = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(){ };
l.Select(kv => kv.Key).Distinct().ToList().DefaultIfEmpty("(empty)").Dump();

The first gives a one element sequence with "key", the second gives a one element sequence with "(empty)".

Have you no elements in the results variable? Or is there one result with the empty string?

Comment: @JT: results have one or several elements or nothing. when sequence haven't any element then i want to add an element like ("Nothing there") to sequence; however i can check it if sequence Count == 0 then add an element, but i want to know can do this with LINQ built-in extension methods like DefaultIfEmpty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `DefaultIfEmpty()` for this purpose. (However, note that the `ToList()` in your query is redundant.)

For example:

```
string[] s1 = new string[] { };
string[] s2 = new string[] { "abc" };

// Outputs "DEFAULT" because the sequence s1 is empty.
foreach (var s in s1.DefaultIfEmpty("DEFAULT"))
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// Outputs "abc" from the sequence s2 and nothing else.
foreach (var s in s2.DefaultIfEmpty("DEFAULT"))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```